# Use a function defined in PowerShell Profile in another function in that Profile

Tags: powershell

In my Powershell profile file `$Env:USERPROFILE\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Microsoft.PowerShell_profile.ps1`, I defined a function `ffs`, which simply converts any given size/number to human-readable format, like for e.g.

```
PS> ffs 2048
2.0K
```

Now, I've have defined another new function `pdu` in the profile, which is basically similar to `du` in unix/linux. But the problem is I'm getting an error while running the `pdu` function. The error says, ffs not recognized as a function, however I've defined it in the profile.

```
The term 'ffs' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was
included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (ffs:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
    + PSComputerName        : localhost
```

Not sure what I need to do more here to be able to use `ffs` in `pdu`. So my question here is: Can a function defined in a Profile be used in another function defined in that same Profile file ? If not, what options/solution do I have (other than creating a module, if possible) to make this work ? The functions are as follows:

```
# File Size formatter
function ffs( [System.UInt64]$size ) {
    If     ($size -gt 1TB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0}T", $size / 1TB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 1GB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0}G", $size / 1GB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 1MB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0}M", $size / 1MB)}
    ElseIf ($size -gt 1KB) {[string]::Format("{0:0.0}K", $size / 1KB)}
    ElseIf ($size -ge 0)   {[string]::Format("{0:0}",    $size)}
    Else                   {""}
}

# Powershell Disk Usage
function pdu( [String]$FoldName ) {
   ...
   Write-Output ""
   Write-Output "`n## Total Size : $( ffs $TotalSize )"
   $AllOutput | Format-Table @{ Label="Size"; Expression={ ffs $_.SizeOnDisk }}, @{Label="Contents"; Expression={ $_.ContentName }}
    ...
}
```

(Edit: Based on the comments below, updating the question.)

Comment: A clean way to approach this would be to create a Module and store it on your Modules folder (generally `$HOME\Documents\PowerShell\Modules`). Then each time PowerShell loads your function will be auto discovered.

Comment: What you describe should work. Can you post confirm both functions are indeed in the same profile file and post the definition of these function or a simplified version of it ? I did try it on my end and did not encounter any issue so I suspect something might be wrong in of the function definition (maybe).

Comment: "however I've defined it in the profile." - did you start a new process after updating the profile? Otherwise do `. $profile` to reload it

Comment: one normally needs to define a function BEFORE it gets used. so ... did your `ffs` get defined in your profile _before_ the one that calls it?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon. Yes. I can do that but ffs is a very small function (5 lines). I don't want to create an entire module just for these few lines. but thanks.

Comment: Yeah I know, a module can be a simple file with the `psm1` extension tho, it's not necessarily complicated and later on if you have more custom function you can add them there for auto loading but this is just a personal recommendation

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen, Yes I've tried it. Still same issue.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey, Yes, the function is defined before.

Comment: @AniketGM - thank you for the added info. however, that error is rather specific ... it means the `ffs` function is not defined at the point where you tried to use it. **_i recommend you start debugging your full code to determine where the scope problem exists._**